# Service or IntentService for user uploading multiple batches of images, if I want to queue batches?

Tags: android, multithreading

In my application, the user can create a product and upload 5 images for it.
The user can go and create a second, a third, a forth and so on products with 5 images for each, while the first 5 images are being uploaded.

This creates a huge multithreading problem in my application.

I want the first batch of images to be uploaded before the next one starts.

At the moment Im using a regular class containing multiple AsyncTasks and callbacks and Im using some Semaphors, but I want to turn this class into a Service or an IntentService that can only be a single instance running at a time.

As I have never used Service or IntentService, I don't know which one will do the job, and then - how to implement it.

I only know that I can stop the Service whenever I want, which is good, because I already have the code that waits for all threads to stop and then terminates the whole operation, but the downfall is that multiple instances of the same Services can be started simultaneously (if im not mistaken) and the other problem is that I need to handle the threading for my service (how do I do that? Create a new thread and put all the code in a runnable to pass to the thread?)

About IntentService I know that it doesnt run on the main thread, but as soon as it starts the sequence of tasks, it dies, so this doesnt help me either, because I want to keep it alive for as long as the uploads are running.

This is all I know about Service and IntentService.

Which one should I choose and how to implement it for my needs?

Should the Service have constructors? Should I use onCreate or onStartCommand?

Comment: There can only be one instance of a `Service` created at one time. If it is started again while it's still running, then `onStartCommand()` will be called on the existing instance. Therefore, you should be able to manage your queue from inside the `Service`, and stop it after it has been processed. You might want to read the documentation and tutorial to understand the service framework and implementation.