# How to execute and receive results from AsyncTasks outside of the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a bunch of AsyncTasks and their callbacks (listener interfaces) that I dont want to have anything to do with the UI thread.

Reading the answer here: [Android : can AsyncTask return in another thread than UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300897/android-can-asynctask-return-in-another-thread-than-ui-thread)
I am left with the impressin that I can only start AsyncTasks from the UI Thread which means the callbacks that I invoke from their onPostExecute methods will also be in the main thread.

How do I move all this logic away from the UI thread?

Comment: AsyncTasks are useful as they give easy ways to modify the UI in the pre/post methods (from the UI thread)...  if you don't want/need that feature, try just using a regular Thread.

Comment: asynctasks are for executing stuff on the background and receiving data on the ui thread. For executing an receiving in the background, any regular thread will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, based on some issues I've had before when trying to run AsyncTasks in an IntentService, I think your assumption that you cannot run an AsyncTask from a non-UI thread is false.

The problem I've found with starting AsyncTasks off the UI thread is not that they don't run or that they cause crashes, but that onPostExecute() doesn't automatically run on the main UI thread after the other stuff finishes. I wouldn't recommend doing it, but you probably could if you wanted to.

But the whole reason AsyncTasks exist are basically to have an easy way to run some code off the UI thread and then be able to alter UI stuff after it's finished. So if you don't want to do anything at all with the UI thread, you shouldn't need to use an AsyncTask at all. If you don't need to run any code on the UI thread, you can just use something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Do your stuff
        }
}).start();
```

Comment: This is good to know for my next project, but right now I have 10 AsyncTasks (insert into db, check for items waiting in the queue for upload, upload items, upload photos, update items with server ids, update photos with server ids, remove items from queue...) that I have already written and I cannot afford rewriting my application, there is too much code. So I need to find a way to live with these asynctasks that I already have somehow.

Comment: Some of those things sound like they should, or potentially could, touch UI stuff (loading indicators, etc). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It might help us answer your question better.

Comment: This is what Im trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401968/service-or-intentservice-for-user-uploading-multiple-batches-of-images-if-i-wan

Comment: Hmm. That's a bit more complicated of a question, but why not just copy/paste the code from your AsyncTasks into synchronous methods, (and then if you actually need an AsyncTask just have it call those methods)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is a good idea. So I get there is no way to make AsyncTasks onPostExecute return in a thread of my choosing?

Comment: The only ways I can think of to do that would involve rewriting as much or more code as the "new Thread()" code that was posted in my answer, but in theory you could. Also, I'm pretty sure onPostExecute() just runs on whatever thread the AsyncTask was started on, but not sure enough to recommend doing it that way.